# Support live stream RTSP on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer-11, rtsp

I am building a web that play ccctv live stream using a rtsp url on Internet Explorer 11.
I found a way how to run rtsp link on c# on Google.
And I confirmed that my rtsp is running in winform picturebox using openCVSharp.
But I could not find a way how to support webservice on IE 11 using .NET.

Does anyone know how to play live stream rtsp link on IE11 through web service?

```
rtsp link for test (big buck bunney bty wowza)
rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

my cctv rtsp link (Hikvision)
rtsp://<ID>:<PW>@<URL>/Streaming/Channels/<CAHNNELNAME>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't play RTSP in IE11 or in any web browser for that matter; unless you use plug-ins (i.e. https://code.videolan.org/videolan/npapi-vlc) - and nobody really likes browser plug-ins. Instead; use a media server:

Most Media Servers (i.e. Wowza, Nimble Streamer, Red5Pro, etc.) support "transmuxing": conversion from one streaming protocol to another; so you capture your RTSP stream, and  playback using a streaming protocol that works in browsers, like HLS (most used) or MPEG-DASH. And if you prefer low-latency playback, then you can use WebRTC which is also a default feature of Wowza.

For WebRTC playback; there's a player and sample JavaScript code included in the Wowza installation. For playback of HLS or MPEG-DASH, I recommend using a video player as very few browser support native playback of HLS or MPEG-DASH from the `<video>` tag only.

Some links to video players:

- https://hls-js.netlify.app/ (open source)
- https://www.theoplayer.com/ (commercial)
- https://videojs.com/ (free)

(or check out Clappr, Bitmovin, JWPlayer, Flowplayer, etc.)